# Trying to work through steps to sum elements in a string

Tags: python, list

I have a string that is a list of numbers. I need to add them all up and print the total.  Everything I try results in a variety of type errors.

```
number = "12345"

# code???

# result should be 15
```

The sum() function won't work on the original code, but it does work on a list like this one:

```
number2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
total = sum(number2)
# result is 20
```

But then the problem is, I can't figure out how to change the string: number to the list: number2. And honestly, I'm not even convinced that this is what I should be trying to do.

It also works on this variation:

```
number = "12345"
num = int(number[0]) + int(number[1])
# result is 3
```

But this is rediculous if the string contains more than a few elements.

I have also tried:

- Creating a new list and interating through the string and appending each index value to the new list. (type error)
- Casting the string and the string elements

(I have also looked tried to solve this by looking on w3schools docs and stackoverflow posts)

Does the answer maybe have something to do with tuples?

Comment: You want to convert each character in the string to a number, and then add it, so `sum(int(i) for i in number)`

Comment: `sum(list(map(int, list(string))))`

Comment: You don't need `list(string)` since `string` is already an iterable of length 1 strings, also no need to convert map to list, since sum takes an iterable which map gives @Adi219

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yeah makes sense actually, also wasn't sure if sum would work directly on map as it returns a generator so `list()`ed it to be safe

Comment: It returns an iterator: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map Also generators are just another way of writing an iterator, so you could say that too!

Comment: I appreciate your patience and help! Got it working!